# received an A- where an X is supposed to be to close a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Somehow I received an A- where an X is supposed to be to close a window. Will someone please enlighten me where I should be looking to find this mistype or error if it was bootstrap or jQuery... What really annoys me is when I recreate this in a fiddle of course it shows an X again. Does anyone have any idea where I may be able to locate this issue?

I am using:
 jQuery-1.11.1, (with smoothness ui)
 bootstrap 3.2.0, (with min.css)

[image]

As you see here all I put was an X: (That's why I think it is a behind the scenes issue with either jQuery or bootstrap)

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select a Specialty Plate</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
```

Comment: look closer. It's an Ã~, not A~. This is a classic case of "you're using a unicode character, but aren't making sure your code/files/etc. support that". Make sure your own HTML file uses `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the very least.

Comment: and the character you are using (bootstrap uses) is × (multiplication) not X or x

Comment: Try using `&times;` (the character entity reference) instead of the character itself.

Comment: Even if changing your `x` to `&times` or `x` or `X` worked, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is right - you should add the UTF-8 meta tag, otherwise you may have vague issues like this in the future, especially if any of your database entries (if you have any) you use to populate pages contain unicode characters.

Comment: What is strange about that is I have the meta tag in there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an character encoding issue.  Your × is different from a regular x (×x).  You can try to delete that x and retype it.